# How can I show a custom ACF product tag in the product archive page with wordpress and elementor?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields, elementor

I've setup a shop with wordpress and elementor page builder, the idea is that people can see handmade products and book a reservation to come see the product in person. I have created a custom product status with ACF to show if a product is available, reserved or sold. This status is properly shown at the product detail page, as can be shown here: https://houtprofessor.with-itwebdesign.nl/product/tafel-op-wielen/. Now the client has asked if this status can also be shown in the product archive page, and I can't find the place where to add this custom field to the products element in elementor. Is there any way to show this product status here under the product title as well?

- So here the status is shown under the price of the product properly: https://houtprofessor.with-itwebdesign.nl/product/tafel-op-wielen/
- And here I need to show the same status but I can't find how: https://houtprofessor.with-itwebdesign.nl/producten/tafels/

How am i able to add this custom field to the product archive?

Comment: isn't that just creating a product archive template in elementor? like.. https://youtu.be/F2gyAeZdU9s?t=303

Comment: Thank you for your reply @Stender, but that unfortunately only shows how to style the options in the standard elementor element products, namely the title, image, price and stars of a product, not how to display a new custom attribute. Elementor support told me it is not standard in there, but im not sure where to change this template with code.

Comment: Hi @marc-hegeman  - I actually had the same problem, So I found out, that you can do it through the custom skin for elementor, free plugin - There is a video tutorial here : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o9HHQ6rJeYU